# Play Framework 2.5 Beginner. JavaForms error

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am trying to implement a Java form in Play framework. I am doing everything as in the documentation, but I have an error.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms

My code:

```
import play.api.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;

public class Products extends Controller {

@Inject FormFactory formFactory;
Form<Product> productForm = formFactory.form(Product.class);
...
```

The error:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that play.data.Form<T> conforms to play.api.data.Form<models.Product>
```

After changing the import library play.api.data to play.data I have this error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
at controllers.Products.<init>(Products.java:18)
while locating controllers.Products
for parameter 2 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:32)
while locating router.Routes
while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
while locating play.api.routing.Router
for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler <init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
while locating play.api.Application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make an import of `play.api.data.Form`, which comes from Play jar, but `FormFactory` returns `play.data.Form`, not the previous ones, so you just need to change import.

Comment: I have already another error. Could you check please the logs above? The error line in Products.Java is in the declaration of the Products class.

Comment: dude, cmon that's not how SO should be used

Comment: the problem that I have limits on daily posts so I try to make the most of it

Comment: @xzayt, there is some problem with DI